# executing queries using haproxy and php websocket

Tags: php, mysql, websocket, haproxy

I'm developing load balancing php app using HAproxy and php websocket [a link](https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets)!.
Users login in to my app (every has own session) and they send form which triggers Execution of mysql queries.

I created  backend as  three instances of websocket server, which run on different IP addresses and ports in background.

Class server

```
class server {
...
}
        $server1=new server('127.0.0.2','9001');
        $server2=new server('127.0.0.3','9002');
        $server3= new server('127.0.0.4','9003');  
    
        $server1->run(); // calling function run from library
        $server2->run();
        $server3->run();
```

**How can I ensure,that mysql queries will be processed by php websockets ?**

Problem is that tasks (performing queries) are not distributed among this servers (I don't see the changes in statistics report).
Of course, I configure properly my haproxy config file.I don't think that haproxy cannot catch my http request an process it.

HAproxy frontend

```
frontend webservers
     bind *:80
     mode http
     default_backend websockets
```

Haproxy backend

```
  backend websockets
      mode http
      balance roundrobin
      server web1 127.0.0.2:9001  check
      server web2 127.0.0.3:9002  check
      server web3 127.0.0.4:9003  check
```

I check haproxy statistics report and I see that haproxy knows about this servers.

It is possible to use websockets for this ? or better solution is node.js ? I didn't see any similiar solution with php websocket. Can php websocket communicate with DB?
If you know some articles about it... Let me know.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need 3 different scripts running at the same time.  Preferably on 3 different machines, otherwise there's no point to load balancing.

server1.php:

```
<?php
require_once('./websockets.php');
class FirstServer extends WebSocketServer { ... }

$server = new FirstServer('127.0.0.2', '9001');
$server->run();
```

server2.php:

```
<?php
require_once('./websockets.php');
class SecondServer extends WebSocketServer { ... }

$server = new SecondServer('127.0.0.3', '9002');
$server->run();
```

server3.php:

```
<?php
require_once('./websockets.php');
class ThirdServer extends WebSocketServer { ... }

$server = new ThirdServer('127.0.0.4', '9003');
$server->run();
```

Then, at your command line, do the following:

```
user@web1$ nohup php /path/to/server1.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &
user@web1$ ssh user@web2 "nohup php /path/to/server2.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
user@web1$ ssh user@web3 "nohup php /path/to/server3.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

A little bit of commentary:

`$server = new Server('127.0.0.4', '9003');` should probably be `$server = new Server('0.0.0.0', '9003');` unless you have a reason (it doesn't even have to be a good reason... just any reason) to not listen on all IP addresses for that machine.  That is, every machine has 127.0.0.1, as well as an address for each configured network interface.  Most people want to listen on all addresses.

I suspect that there's absolutely nothing wrong with your connection to the MySQL server.  The issue is that `$server1->run()` never returns, so never executes the next line, `$server2->run()`.